# ERROR al obtener un OUTPUT de un procedimiento almacenado con spring

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot

Como podría obtener el output que devuelve el procedimiento, lo que intento hacer, cuando mando a llamar mi procedimiento guarda la información pero me da error al momento de devolver el id con el que se guardo, muestro mi procedimiento

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spINSERT_Inventarios]
    @tipoEquipo             int,
    @idUsuario              int,
    @usuarioResguardo       int,
    @inventario             varchar(200),
    @serial                 varchar(100),
    @marca                  varchar(100),
    @modelo                 varchar(100),
    @observaciones          varchar(100),
    @estado                 varchar(100),
    @usuarioAlt             varchar(100),
    @fecha                  date,
    @idInventario           int=0 output

AS
BEGIN
    
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[inventarios]
            ([idTipoEquipo],
             [idUsuario],
             [idUsuarioResguardo],
             [inventario],
             [serial],
             [marca],
             [modelo],
             [observaciones],
             [estado],
             [baja],
             [usuarioAlt],
             [fechaAdquirido])
    VALUES(@tipoEquipo,@idUsuario,@usuarioResguardo,@inventario,@serial,
            @marca,@modelo,@observaciones,@estado,0,@usuarioAlt,@fecha)

    SELECT @idInventario = SCOPE_IDENTITY() 

     SELECT @idInventario AS id
    
    RETURN @idInventario
END
```

Muestro el resultado del procedimiento

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

todo bien, lo ejecuto en sql y me devuelve el resultado
pero ya en spring me sale el siguiente error

```
SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
The statement did not return a result set.
Error insertando el inventario 
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
```

Muestro la forma en la que lo estoy mandando a llamar al procedimiento

```
 @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(value="{CALL spINSERT_Inventarios(:tipoEquipo,:idUsuario,:usuarioResguardo,:inventario,:serial,:marca,:modelo,:observa,:estado,:usuarioAlt,:fecha)}", nativeQuery=true)
    List<Integer> agregarInventario(@Param("tipoEquipo") int tipoEquipo,@Param("idUsuario") int idUsuario,@Param("usuarioResguardo") int usuarioResguardo,@Param("inventario") String inventario,
                           @Param("serial") String serial,@Param("marca") String marca,@Param("modelo") String modelo,@Param("observa") String observa,@Param("estado") String estado,
                           @Param("usuarioAlt")String usuarioAlt,@Param("fecha") Date fecha);
```

lo estoy obteniendo con una lista, ya que al ejecutar el procedimiento en sql, me devuelve 3 datos, tambien, lo coloque en vez de Integer como String, y tambien obteniendo solo el parametro sin el List

Gracias por la ayuda que me puedan ofrecer, ya que llevo dias con el problema

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que veo, estas utilizando Spring Data JPA. Si es el caso, te recomiendo utilizar Spring JDBC para el consumo de Stored Procedures.

```
SimpleJdbcCallback proc = new SimpleJdbcCallback(jdbcTemplate)
   .withProcedureName("spINSERT_Inventarios")

//... parametros de inicializacion y mas

Map<String, Object> in = new MapSqlParameterSource();

in.addValue("idTipoEquipo", TU_VALOR);
//... los demás parametros

Map<String, Object> out = procedure.execute(in);

int idInventario = (Int)out.get("idInventario");
```

Comment: ok lo, intentare, seria hacerlo antes del repositorio, cierto

Comment: A repositorio te refieres a la clase que tiene el metodo agregarInventario??  en tal caso, sería utilizar una clase que extienda de org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure, sobreescribir el constructor padre (DataSource, spName) y poner un metodo, por ejemplo, execute y que reciba como parametro el out del ejemplo anterior. Ese execute podria retornar cualquiere cosa, por ejemplo un idInventario